# Defining a class instance in one function, referencing it in another?

Tags: python, class

```
class neato:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dance = "I love to dance yadayaadadad!"

def main():
    happyDance()
    print(happy.dance)

def happyDance():
    happy = neato()


main()
```

I would rather like to be able to reference my class objects module wide. This is a little experiment of that. Is there any way to do this? Currently, the code prints a name error.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the instance of Neato made in the function happyDance:

```
class neato:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dance = "I love to dance yadayaadadad!"

def main():
    happy = happyDance()
    print(happy.dance)

def happyDance():
    return neato()


main()
```